# AWS State Machine that can "branch" into a different State Machine by ARN

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I want to have an AWS State machine that can branch the execution graph into a separate state machine like,

[image: State Machine drawing]

Where the execution is branching into the other state machine. I should note that ideally, I could go cross account. From [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-state-machine-structure.html) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-states.html), we get information about creating the compute graph for state machines, but it's not obvious if I can/cannot make a [task](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-task-state.html) specify a separate state machine for the execution resource.

What I want can be done with Lambda functions making [start_execution](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/stepfunctions.html#SFN.Client.start_execution) calls, but that's no super elegant.

Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's good question, but in my experience with Step Functions - you can't "branch" into a different state machine.

As you mentioned - it's possible to start execution of another state machine, but moreover than "not elegant" it's almost impossible to "halt" state machine and continue execution when another execution ends.

"Almost" - because actually you can achieve that by making "task" state that is looped and lambda inside periodically polls that another execution...

I would suggest you to just copy+paste that different state machine inside your initial state machine.

Comment: Copy and paste isn't an option because the AWS accounts have different development teams and the platforms need to be developed independently.

Comment: Oh well... so yeah, in that case looks like that "not elegant" solution is the only way... but it can be mess, because need that cross-account permissions for Lambda to start execution of state machine on another account + permissions for Lambda that will periodically poll that started execution